# Visual Basic: How to reference the path of database on dropbox for multiple users

Tags: sql, visual-studio

Please be sure to read and understand what I am looking for...

My classmates and I are working on a project and we want to use dropbox to save all files. Now the problem comes in that we have to change the path every time we test and change code. We want to know if there is another method other than linking like this :

C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Project\Database\Student Management.mdb

So that it would be the same on both computers... for example C:\Dropbox etc

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox...")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the userprofile-folder, you can get it with [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx):

```vb
Dim userProf As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
Dim dbPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(userProf, "Dropbox\Project\Database\Student Management.mdb")
Dim con As New OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}", dbPath))
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. I did change come code on it, though.

Comment: nothing major or worth nothing,just took the dbPath out. But thanks a lot man